# Why do i get different result when sorting with one random seed?

Tags: sorting, random, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 1.3.2 in production with a node of 2 masters with data.

I have a realy strange behavior when i search with a fixed random seed on this cluster. I get exactly 2 different sortings of my results. 
It seems that every node holds its one random "seed" and depending which node delivers the result the sorting is different.

I want to get same sortings with the same seed.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: one work around would be to  use [preference with custom string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html) to get a more consistent result set

Comment: I will try this appraoch but i think there is something other wrong. Why should there be a difference which node assembles the request? All data and shards are replicated and should be stable... Or do i miss something here?